# Add image to Ribbon Button in Sandbox

Tags: ribbon, sandbox-solution

I've created a simple SharePoint ribbon tab with a button on it; the button XML looks like this:

```
              <Button
                Id="Ribbon.MyTab.MainGroup.HelloButton"
                Command="MyTab.HelloCommand"
                Description="Says Hello"
                LabelText="Hello"
                Image32by32="/_layouts/MyCustomSPTab/icon3232.png"
                TemplateAlias="cust4" />
```

I know the compiler complains about deploying images to the sandbox.

Is it possible to add an image to a ribbon button in a sandboxed solution? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438085.aspx):

> Please note that CustomActionGroups cannot be added through a Sandboxed feature in SharePoint 2010. This requires a farm solution in order to be shown (it doesn't provide an error if it is a sandbox).
>
> CustomActions can be added to existing SharePoint 2010 groups in a sandboxed feature.

Also you should keep in mind that Sandbox solution cannot deploy any files to the file system by security reason (All files are stored in contatnt DB for Sandbox solutions). I think that you can create your Module (in VS2010 you can see this temlate if you click add new item on existed project). Then put your picture to this Module and set reference to this picture in your custom action.

Answer (score -2):

If you have SharePoint Designer, you may want to try this - [Adding Button to ribbon using SharePoint Designer](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-add-button-to-ribbon.html)

Also, have a look at this. [Customizing SharePoint Online with SharePoint Designer 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh428136.aspx)

Comment: The OP was asking about sandbox solutions, not using SPD.